# How to get validated data from Validator instance in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

I manually created a `Validator`, but i can't find a method to get the validated data.
For `Request`, validated data return from `$request->validate([...])`
For `FormRequest`, it's return from `$formRequest->validated()`
But with `Validator`, i don't see a method like those 2 above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Validator facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $attributes);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $validator->errors();
}

//If validation passes, return valid fields
return $validator->valid();
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_valid

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Validator facade with `make` it will return a validator instance. This validator instance has methods like `validate()`, `fails()` and so on. You can look those methods up in the validator class or in [the laravel api-documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html).

Answer (score -1):

Writing The Validation Logic

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
 ]);

 // The blog post is valid...
}
```

Displaying The Validation Errors

```
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
@endif

<!-- Create Post Form -->
```

Comment: Sorry, I knew this `$validatedData = $request->validate([...])`.
What i asked is validated data from Validator.